# Using After Insert Trigger to only insert specific values and a specific set of rows

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I have a trigger I'm working that will insert values mostly present. Minus 2 that I statically place into the trigger itself. The trigger executes fine, but it repeats many inserts and I can't figure out why. In this particular instance I want it to insert values based on things not already inserted into the trigger based table.

I select two values from one table and 3 from the trigger table. I want to insert a new GUID and the number 0 in the "selected" column for all values NOT found in the trigger table. In this instance there's only 10 to choose from .. (10 rows in the `[CIF_SublineType]` table.) So if insert 2 rows, I'm trying to insert only the other 8. But this current set up inserts upwards of 100 or so of the same values

I've tried multiple variations of this trigger and some do nothing. Others give me multiples of the same row.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[UpdateUniqSubLineType]
ON  [GTU_Apps].[dbo].[TestTableCIF] 
AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO GTU_Apps.dbo.TestTableCIF (UniqSublineID, UniqSublineType, UniqLineType, UniqLine, UniqPolicy, Selected, LineName)
        SELECT DISTINCT
            NEWID(), SLT.UniqSublineType, TT.UniqLineType, TT.UniqLine, 
            TT.UniqPolicy, 0, SLT.SubLine_Name 
        FROM 
            [GTU_Apps].[dbo].[CIF_SublineType] AS SLT 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
            GTU_Apps.dbo.TestTableCIF AS TT ON SLT.UniqLineType = TT.UniqLineType 
        WHERE
            SLT.SubLine_Name <> TT.LineName 
            AND LT.UniqLineType = TT.UniqLineType
END
```

I would like to show a screenshot of the table `[CIF.SublineType]` so you could see that I'm only trying to insert values NOT already in the trigger table. In this case `TestTableCIF`, but I can't figure out how to upload an image. Any help would be greatly appreciated

EDIT. Using the inserted table:

```
ON  [GTU_Apps].[dbo].[TestTableCIF] 
   AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN

INSERT INTO GTU_Apps.dbo.TestTableCIF 
(UniqSublineID, UniqSublineType, UniqLineType, UniqLine, UniqPolicy, Selected, LineName)

SELECT distinct
NEWID(), SLT.UniqSublineType, i.UniqLineType, i.UniqLine, i.UniqPolicy, 0, SLT.SubLine_Name 

FROM 
inserted as i 
join [GTU_Apps].[dbo].[CIF_SublineType] AS SLT ON
i.LineName = SLT.SubLine_Name AND i.UniqLineType = SLT.UniqLineType
where i.UniqSublineType <> SLT.UniqSublineType

END
```

Editing this for comments below. 
UniqLineType is the key used to pull all the UniqSublineTypes. Here are the 10 Guids stored and depending on what is not inserted, the trigger compares that and inserts these from the CIF_SublineType table.

```
  /* MCAL subline GUIDs */
    public string mcalBIPD = "151743CE-4750-44C1-A950-613057C1D892";
    public string mcalHired = "F4916ABE-8FFB-4DC4-A546-32603647781B";
    public string mcalNonOwned = "8FA5A75E-71D1-44BD-91EA-0B14F7D08FF6";
    public string mcalPIP = "4F5AC1A8-0BC9-437C-B16A-4DA64B7FE28B";
    public string mcalAddPIP = "6FE73B23-D437-4FC4-83DE-2751B0966A80";
    public string mcalMedPayments = "BB9307AD-EE95-4703-BF45-C482E09537E6";
    public string mcalUMPD = "E23DAAE0-3E4F-4A52-8A2F-C01501CD0295";
    public string mcalUMCSL = "1228C123-32CF-483E-8F8B-3F7B01ABF53A";
    public string mcalUIMCSL = "04096A7A-E42A-4D6A-B0AE-49B832005C41";
    public string mcalTerror = "7EF66420-060C-49E7-AC81-06C5ECB6CC2F";
    var MCAL = '5cc3cb18-5b52-454d-88c7-2670501946b4';
```

these are found using the MCAL var above from the CIF_Subline table.

Comment: What is immediately striking me is the fact you're never referencing the `Inserted` pseudo table - this is a system-provided table that contains the rows that were inserted in the `INSERT` command that triggered this trigger. You seem to be copying around potentially way too many rows - you need to read up about how to make use of `Inserted` in your trigger!

Comment: @marc_s thanks for the assist. Unfortunately, even after reading about and testing with the Inserted table, I'm in the same position. I've tried every possible combination I can come up with. In theory it seems quite simple. There's 10 possible rows that can be inserted at one time. Locating the ones already present and using the trigger to insert the ones that aren't is the goal. I've used the inserted table, but left with the same results. Either way too many or none at all. I'll edit my post to show the change.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to insert a new GUID and the number 0 in the "selected" column
>   for all values NOT found in the trigger table.

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO GTU_Apps.dbo.TestTableCIF 
(UniqSublineID, UniqSublineType, UniqLineType, UniqLine, UniqPolicy, Selected, LineName)

SELECT distinct
NEWID(), SLT.UniqSublineType, i.UniqLineType, i.UniqLine, i.UniqPolicy, 0, SLT.SubLine_Name 

FROM 
[GTU_Apps].[dbo].[CIF_SublineType] AS SLT 
left join inserted i on i.UniqLineType = SLT.UniqLineType 
where i.UniqLineType is null
and SLT.UniqLineType is not null
and SLT.UniqSublineType is not null
and SLT.UniqLineType is not null
and SLT.UniqLine is not null
and SLT.UniqPolicy is not null
```

The select statement will get all the entries that do not fit with the `inserted` table.

Comment: thanks for trigger to try. I tried it, but it didn't work. I have all columns set to NOT NULL, so I get an error telling me cannot insert null values into the table. I changed is null to IS NOT NOT NULL, including different join parts and I get either 138 rows inserted or 22. However, I'm only inserting 2, so 8 should be what is inserted. I'm at a loss on this one.

Comment: @swapmeet_Lou so is your `UniqSublineType` actually unique or is it just called that way? something must be wrong with either the database design or the actual data inside your tables.

Comment: Xaphas. Fair question. UniqSublineType is unique. There is only one value of that type. I can't post a picture, but I'll edit my post above and show you the values. There is only 10 of them.

Comment: @swapmeet_Lou I think we used the wrong key: edited answer

Comment: I know. I tried it the very same way thinking we used the wrong key. But here's what happened. I inserted two rows. Those insert as they should. Then it proceeds to insert 116 more rows of null values on the UniqLineType (our key) and UniqLine, UniqPolicy. All values that are already present.